# Delphi XE2 DataSnap Life-cycle with Android connection

Tags: android, delphi, session, delphi-xe2, datasnap

I have a DataSnap Server with DSServerClass.LifeCycle=Session (exposes a descent class of TDSServerModule).

When the client connects the TDSServerModule, is created and remains in memory as long as session was, - this made a datasnap connection (tunneling) - thats ok.

When connect by a Android (Mobile connected), and the TDSServerModule is created/destroyed by call (instance).. This makes a REST connection...

I have a small demo with this.

Any idea to resolve this problem...

Thanks in advance,
Pedro Lopes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

REST is by definition stateless. From documentation on *[Server Class LifeCycle](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Server_Class_LifeCycle)*:

> For a REST client connection, if Session LifeCycle is used on the
> server class, it behaves like Invocation LifeCycle.

It is by-design. What is your problem precisely?

Comment: Thanks, my problem is reading a big dataset. I have the fooling steps: 1 - Open, preparate; 
2 - Load 40 rows
3 - repeat until eof ()

Comment: In that case you have to transfer state from client to server. For example define custom servermethod with input parameters StartRow and EndRow and returning the corresponding dataset with all rows in between. This technique is called 'incremental fetching'.

Comment: but starting the query in every call is to slow... perhaps I must store the connection and the query in session variable... is it this a good approach?

Comment: Hard to tell on forehand what is bottleneck. But if mobile-device client needs hundreds of data rows it is not bad idea I think to reconsider design. Anyway, Alister Christie has nice video on 'Preserving State in DataSnap REST Servers'. http://learndelphi.tv/video/064/RestServer.html Good luck!

Comment: Do not store the full dataset in the session. You can use a cache which holds the records so all sessions can share it. Otherwise your server will run out of memory very soon. Avoid session data whenever possible.